# SharePoint Workflow not automatically starting

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow in SPD that has been working great, starts automatically, does what it should.  I am building new pages around the same list but in a different library from the first one.  So, the workflow should still work since it is the same list, correct?  It is not starting automatically but it will run manually.  Is there anything I need to change in Designer to get it to associate with the new page/form?

Scott

Comment: I think you need to be more specific on how this is set up? Same list but a different library? Then it is not the same list... Try to describe it with list and library names :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, i am not sure what you mean about "building new pages around the same list but in a different library from the first one"

I guess you are using a reusable workflow with a certain content type. You add the content type in another library and try to trigger the workflow again. You may need to [associate the workflow to the new list](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx).

If this does not help you. Please elaborate more information about your workflow setup, relationships between the lists, libraries and pages with more names.